# Ruby Controller API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new to this site, so I hope I do not make mistakes during the creation of this post or breaking any rules (I've read all the rules but not everything is clear yet). I have two questions and I hope someone can help me with this. I switched from php to ruby on rails yesterday and it was fairly easy to rvm using the latest ruby and rails version. After some tutorials I started a application with devise and slim.

Now I read that by means the use of the devise model `:token_authenticatable` you enable the so called api requests. Now I would like to create a controller called *tasks*. If I make a controller, then I can call it via the internet page which is not the intention. The intention is that this is only possible through the api request (I still need to figure out how to enable this)

Is it possible to call a controller that only retrievable through an API request and not through a web browser?

Thanks for your time and thank you for your answer and help.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at this project: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @MurifoX I could add this to my existing application but I am worried that the change from `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base` to `class ApplicationController < ActionController::API` destroys the rest of the application like the frontpage. I'd like to have the api in the same location as the website and the login, etc. So the whole application (website and api) are using the same database. Is there a solution for that? Google seems to failing in that manner. Thank you for your kindly answer and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off what others have said, I think the best way for you to do this is threefold:

1) call [`respond_to :json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) in the beginning of your controller, and [`respond_with`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) in your API actions. e.g.

```
class TasksController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json

  def api_call
    @something = Task.find(…)
    respond_with @something
  end
end
```

2) Format your responses using something like RABL (check out [this article](http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/))

3) Check out the [rails-api](http://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) project for inspiration (or use it)

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict the formats to accept only json (or anything else) in your tasks controller.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I'll look later into that.